# shopify-api-node: promise not returning value

Tags: node.js, api, express, shopify, shopify-app

Setting up a node.js app to retrieve order(s) information from shopify. I'm trying to store that data and run some logic, but I can't seem to get a hold of it.

---

THIS WORKS:

```
shopify.order.list()
.then(function(orders){
    console.log(orders);
  });
```

---

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
var orders_json;
shopify.order.list()
    .then(function(orders){
        orders_json=orders;
          //console.log(orders);
      });

console.log(orders_json); //returns undefined
```

---

Comment: You have to work with `orders` inside of that `.then` function because `shopify.orders.list` is asynchronous. Hoisting variables does not work like that. Can you give a better example of what you are trying to do? It would help use better determine if you need another promise, a callback or can use async/await.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin yeah, i just want to assign whats in "orders" to a global variable and then sift through the information to separate individual orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me introduce you to the world of [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). As long as you declare your function as `async` and the function you are "awaiting" returns a promise, you can handle this in a more synchronous way. Have a look at the docs linked above. Notice how I called the async function after it was declared. You can't call await outside the scope of an async function.

```
async function fetchOrders() {
  try {
    const orders_json = await shopify.order.list();
    // do stuff with orders_json

    return orders_json;
  } catch(err) {
    // handle err
  }
}

const orders = fetchOrders();
```